Implement Image Masking in NextJS
My team is implementing the image masking feature for a webapp project. We are opening the image in a canvas and user can make the mask on this image.
The end result should be a black and white image. With white portion, that is marked by the user and black part which is not touched by the user. We are using - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-canvas-draw but it is not making the mask properly, leaving many pixels black which supposed to be white.
Any suggestions on how we can implement it Or any good library that you are aware of?
Thanks!!

try Fabric.js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

const ImageMask = ({ src }) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current);
    fabric.Image.fromURL(src, function(img) {
      img.selectable = false;
      canvas.add(img);
    });

    const rect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      fill: 'white',
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      selectable: true
    });
    canvas.add(rect);

    rect.on('modified', function() {
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
      ctx.fillRect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.width, rect.height);
    });

    return () => canvas.dispose();
  }, [src]);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={800} height={600} />;
};

export default ImageMask;

or Konva.js
import { Stage, Layer, Image, Rect } from 'react-konva';
import useImage from 'use-image';

const ImageMask = ({ src }) => {
  const [image] = useImage(src);
  return (
    <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
      <Layer>
        <Image image={image} />
        <Rect
          x={20}
          y={20}
          width={100}
          height={100}
          fill='white'
          draggable
        />
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
};

export default ImageMask;

